# How to call a a field of one model A into another model B so that b can work as a view

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a model called Department, Course. Models are as follow

This is the model for departments and course

```
class Departments(models.Model):
    Department_Id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Department_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Department_Code = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Course(models.Model):
    Course_Id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Department_Id = models.ForeignKey(Departments, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Course_Code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to create a model called view which can be later on called for search. I want a view model in a such a way that it consit of the data in concat form i.e. name= Department_name+  Course_Name

```
class View (models.model):
       view_id=  models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        Name=  Department_name(I want this from Departments table) 
        +  Course_Name(I want this from Course table)
```

I try using one to one relation . I would really appricate the help

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you'd want to do that. It's never a good idea to duplicate data from one model into another one, as it can lead to inconsistencies.

You can add a ForeignKey in View to your `Course` model and then when you do `f"{view.course.name} {view.course.department.name}"` you already have your string:

```
class View(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def name(self):
        return f"{self.course.name} {self.course.department.name}"
```

Notes:

- Don't call your foreign key `Department_id` because it's not referring to the id but to the object itself in the Django ORM: `department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. As you can see, this makes reading the code much simpler: `self.course.Department_id` is a `Department` object not an integer, so `self.course.department` makes more sense.
- Don't prefix your field names with the class, it just makes the code so much less readable: Do you prefer `department.name` or `department.Department_name`?
- The `View` model is still a mystery to me, as you can search without it. You can search for example for courses with a matching department name like this:

  ```
  Course.objects.filter(department__name__icontains="maths")
  ```

  which will return all courses with "maths" in their department name.
- Remove all the ids from your models, they are created automatically by Django anyway (and called `id`). Again, `department.id` is much easier to read than `department.Department_id`. Also in your code, you have to generate the ids yourself since you don't set them to auto-populate.